# How can I test my machine learning model on a machine with no Mathematica?

Tags: machine-learning, scripting

I need to test my machine learning models that I’ve built using `Predict` on 100,000 observations. The problem is that the machine where the testing is done doesn’t have *Mathematica*.  I would like to find an alternative to the cloud if possible. I don’t think I have or can have enough cloud credit to do the testing.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what `Method` you pick.

If you use `Method->"LinearRegression"` it is possible to do like `PredictorInformation[p, "Function"]`, which returns the formula that you can use in any code.

If you use `Method->"NeuralNetwork"` it is possible to export the network to MXNet, which you can then use (with some caveats) on other machines.

```
(p /. PredictorFunction -> Association)["Model", "Network"]
```

This will return the trained Neural Network, which you can then export to MXNet:

```
Export["mynet.json", (p /. PredictorFunction -> Association)["Model", "Network"], "MXNet"]
```

This exports a `.json` file (the network specification) and a `.params` file, which contains the layer weights.

Caveats include `NetEncoder`s and `NetDecoder`s not being included in this specification, so if you trained on images or audio or something, you need to recreate the encoder in your chosen language.

If you use `Method->"GaussianProcess"`, it's possible that `PredictorInformation[p, "OptimizedGaussianProcessModel"]` will give you something useful - but to be honest, I have no idea what a Gaussian Process is. My expectation is that the result of that function gives you a list of parameters to plug into some standard formula, but I haven't a clue unfortunately.

If you use `Method->"NearestNeighbor"`, it's not clear to me that you can export anything useful. This method appears to use `Nearest` underneath, and I am unclear on whether you can export a `NearestFunction` usefully. If this is your issue, probably best to search here and then open a new question if it's not obvious.

If you use `Method->"DecisionTree"`, `Method->"RandomForest"` or `Method->"GradientBoostedTrees"`, it is unclear to me that you can export any part of the results meaningfully.

If can be useful to look at the `Normal` of your trained `PredictorFunction` (eg, `Normal@p`), as well as `PredictorInformation[p, "Properties"]`. They may enlighten you on what your predictor is doing underneath. (In future versions of WL, just `Information` should work.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to export it using something like mxnet.

Comment: ThankYou!  Can you please direct me to a website?

Comment: https://mxnet.apache.org

Comment: How can a `PredictorFunction` (which is what `Predict` returns) be exported to MXNet?

Comment: @C.E. I believe that if you use `Method->"NeuralNetwork"` it's possible by doing some spelunking - if you check `InputForm` of the `PredictorFunction` there might be a network in there that you can then export.

Comment: @C.E. Actually, see my answer, I have an implementation.

Comment: @CarlLange Cool, a great answer to this question I think.

Answer (score -2):

You may export the model to CDF player pro and use this setting to make the tests.

Comment: To what "setting" are you referring?

Comment: I believe they may have meant "setting" as in "environment".